# MS SQL Server: Total count from self and subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have the following tables:

Table 1: foo

```
id  should_be_counted (bit)
1   1
2   0
3   0
4   1
```

Table 2: bar

```
id  foo_id  should_be_counted (bit)
1   1       0
2   1       1
3   2       1
```

How can I query the data so that I get the total count for each foo (where foo.should_be_counted = 1) and all its related bar's (where bar.should_be_counted = 1).

Expected Results:

```
id  count
1   2
2   1
3   0
4   1
```

Sample Data (taken from [Susang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6222808/susang)'s answer and updated):

```
DECLARE @foo AS TABLE(id INT, should_be_counted bit)
INSERT INTO @foo VALUES
(1,1),
(2,0),
(3,0),
(4,1)

DECLARE @bar AS TABLE(id INT, foo_id INT, should_be_counted bit)
INSERT INTO @bar VALUES
(1,1,0),
(2,1,1),
(3,2,1)
```

Comment: Why does the value "1" have a count of 2?  What logic are you using?

Comment: It has a count of 2 because it "should be counted" and it has one bar entry which should also be counted.

Comment: Perhaps showing us your attempt will help us understand your goal/logic here.

Comment: You should read this:  https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple `left join` with `group by` wil get your desired output

```
DECLARE @foo AS TABLE(id INT, should_be_counted INT)
INSERT INTO @foo VALUES
(1,1),
(2,0),
(3,0),
(4,1)

DECLARE @bar AS TABLE(id INT, foo_id INT, should_be_counted INT)
INSERT INTO @bar VALUES
(1,1,0),
(2,1,1),
(3,2,1)

SELECT f.id, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN f.should_be_counted>0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)+MAX(t.tot) AS [count]
FROM @foo f
OUTER APPLY(SELECT COUNT(*) tot 
            FROM @bar b WHERE b.foo_id = f.id AND b.should_be_counted > 0) t
GROUP BY f.id
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
id  count
1   2
2   1
3   0
4   1
```

Comment: should_be_counted is of type bit which is incompatible in the add operator.

Comment: This is why you should supply DDL in your question, it helps prevent people wasting their time!

Comment: @Susang, it works as expected. Why do you use bit > 0 rather than bit = 1? Also, why do you use MAX and not SUM for t.tot?

Comment: Count function considered any not null value as `1` so I added condition `> 0`. Used `MAX` to avoid this column in the group by and yes you can also use `SUM` instead or just `t.tot` and place the same in group by clause as `GROUP BY f.id,t.tot`.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand should_be_counted is always 1 or 0. Then this would be a simple and clear way:

```
select id, sum(cast(should_be_counted as int)) as cnt
from 
(
  select id, should_be_counted
  from foo 
  union all
  select foo_id, should_be_counted
  from bar 
) tmp
group by id;
```

[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=39752d2a9a4cf593a6bce7868b660bee)

Note: I later saw that it was bit, then would work as I said.

Comment: should_be_counted is of type bit (0 or 1).

Comment: @jhhwilliams, yes I later saw that. Then it would do just what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think you simply need :

```
select f.id, case when b.cnt = 0 then f.should_be_counted else b.cnt end
from foo f outer apply
     ( select count(*) as cnt
       from bar b
       where b.foo_id = f.id
     ) b;
```

Comment: Where does a.should_be_counted come from?

Comment: The result for foo(id=4) is 0 which is not correct. It should be 1 because it, itself should be counted.

Comment: @jhhwilliams. . . Yes, you need `case` expression.

Comment: your updated answer works. I just need a minute to figure out why/how. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me you need join and count

```
   select f.id,coalesce((count(*),f.should_be_counted)) from foo f left join bar b on f.id=b.foo_id
    group by f.id
```